# cv2.filter2D: no results if kernel size is too big

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, filtering

I'm trying to learn how to use OpenCV, and following the basic tutorials.
Testing the simple cv2.filter2D, I'm experiencing a problem...if the kernel size is higher than a certain number, the program won't produce any output.

So, I'm writing something like:

```py
img = cv2.imread('images/img.jpg')

kernel = np.ones((n,n),np.float32)/n**2
smoothed = cv2.filter2D(img,-1,kernel)

cv2.imshow('orig', img)
cv2.imshow('smoothed', smoothed)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and the problem is that, for n>11, the smoothed image is not produced (I tried to save it or show it, but I got no results). Tried with various images of different sizes, but always with the same result.
What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks!

<s>EDIT:
Ok, short update.

The script works normally, and produces the blurred image, when I execute it from the terminal (I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with OpenCv 4.1.0).
The problem is when I try to execute it in Pycharm, and in this case it throws the error "Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)", which should indicate some sort of...segmentation problem, as far as I understand?
Sorry for the initial vagueness, I was in a little bit of a hurry and didn't notice the Pycharm message!</s>

EDIT:
New update.
As crazy as it sounds, I tried to run the script both from terminal and from Pycharm, and now it doesn't work from either of them! I honestly have no clue how this is possible, as far as I remember I didn't change anything significant!
Anyway, if it can still be helpful, when running from terminal the sys.path is:

```
['/home/lews/PycharmProjects/opencv/00_basics',
'/home/lews/PycharmProjects/tf_models/research',
'/home/lews/PycharmProjects/tf_models/research/slim',
'/home/lews/PycharmProjects/opencv/00_basics',
'/home/lews/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python37.zip',
'/home/lews/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7',
'/home/lews/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
'/home/lews/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

while from Pycharm is:

```
['/home/lews/PycharmProjects/opencv/00_basics',
'/snap/pycharm-professional/159/helpers/pydev',
'/home/lews/PycharmProjects/opencv',
'/snap/pycharm-professional/159/helpers/pycharm_display',
'/snap/pycharm-professional/159/helpers/third_party/thriftpy',
'/snap/pycharm-professional/159/helpers/pydev',
'/home/lews/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python37.zip',
'/home/lews/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7',
'/home/lews/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
'/home/lews/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
'/snap/pycharm-professional/159/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend',
'/home/lews/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
'/home/lews/PycharmProjects/opencv']
```

Again, neither of them work, in both cases the blurred image isn't produced.
When running from terminal, it returns the error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

while with Pycharm, as I said, I get

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Comment: Which version of OpenCV? What platform? What exactly does "image is not produced" mean? What exactly does the function return in that case? Provide an image that can reproduce it and a concrete example of the alleged failure. I can't reproduce this with sizes well exceeding 11, using a number of different OpenCV builds (in the 3.x and 4.x range).

Comment: @Carlo it sounds like there's a problem with the environment. Maybe the python wrapper or some of its dependencies are not on the path when running from PyCharm. Can you print out the `sys.path` at the start of your program and compare it when running from the terminal versus from PyCharm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A kernel of size n=11 is huge, and computationally incredibly expensive to apply to an image. There are typically upper limits on kernel sizes for convolutions to avoid unreasonably long processing times.

According to the documentation:

- [OpenCV filter2D reference documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#void%20filter2D(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20ddepth,%20InputArray%20kernel,%20Point%20anchor,%20double%20delta,%20int%20borderType))

> The function uses the DFT-based algorithm in case of sufficiently large kernels (~`11 x 11` or larger) and the direct algorithm (that uses the engine retrieved by createLinearFilter() ) for small kernels.

This implies that it should produce some output, albeit via the DFT algorithm. Perhaps the DFT alternative doesn't support float32 pixel type?

Comment: Thank you! As I said, I'm studying this stuff now, so I don't really have a feeling of when I'm overstepping and using stuff which is too computationally expensive! As a matter of fact, in the tutorial I was following they used a 15x15 kernel, so I didn't suspect 11x11 could be too much. I'll look into why it's not switching to the DFT algorithm.

Comment: This doesn't really seem to address the question, does it? Yeah, it's not a good idea to use huge kernels, but I can't reproduce any issue the likes of which OP claims to have, even with 101x101 sized kernel (takes about a second to run), and using range of OpenCV releases since 3.0. It certainly shouldn't return "nothing"... but who knows what is actually happening, the description is quite vague.

Comment: Dan, I added a few info in the question!

Comment: @DanMašek agreed. Especially with the new info from OP, there appears to be something environmental going on.